# Button is Showing GMSMarkers but isn't Hiding it, How do I get it to do both

Tags: swift, xcode, uibutton, gmsmapview

Im creating an app that shows different locations. Currently when a button is pressed the car locations pop up on the map, however I want to then hide those shown markers if that same button is pressed again.

This is the function that takes a snapshot of my database from firebase, it then inserts the GMSMarker into the location.

```
 func showCarIcon() {

    ref = Database.database().reference()

    ref.child("location").observe(.childAdded) { (snapshot:DataSnapshot) in
        if let dict = snapshot.value as? [String:AnyObject] {
            if dict["Activity"] as! String == "Car" {
            let longitude = dict["Longitude"] as! String
            let lattitude = dict["Lattitude"] as! String
            let title = dict["Title"] as! String
                self.carIconArray.insert(coordinate(carLat: lattitude, carLng: longitude), at: 0)
               let n = self.carIconArray.count
               let heightWidth = self.mapView.frame.height
                for marker in 1...n {
                    let carMarker = GMSMarker()
                    let carIconView = UIImage(named: "carPin")
                    let image = carIconView
                    let location = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: Double(lattitude)!, longitude: Double(longitude)!)
                    carMarker.position = location
                    carMarker.icon = image
                    carMarker.title = title
                    carMarker.icon = self.image(image!, scaledToSize: CGSize(width: heightWidth/6, height: heightWidth/6))
                    func displayIt() {
                        if self.carNumber == "1" {
                            carMarker.map = self.mapView
                        } else {
                            carMarker.map = nil
                        }
                    }

                    displayIt()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So this is the action function for when button is pressed.

```
var carNumber = String()

@IBAction func showCar(_ sender: Any) {
    if motorisedVehicleButtonActive {
        motorisedVehicleButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "carO"), for: .normal)
        carNumber = "1"
    } else {
        motorisedVehicleButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "car"), for: .normal)
        carNumber = "0"
    }
    print(carNumber)
    motorisedVehicleButtonActive = !motorisedVehicleButtonActive
    showCarIcon()
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me explain what is issue with your code.

1. You are creating new marker every time when button press. So, new marker have different object id than older.
2. When you try to remove it, it will not works just because of it's different marker than you placed on map.
3. So you need to store marker in array and on remove time, get icon from array and remove it from map.

First you need to create array of `GMSMarker`, because you have to store every marker which is placed on map.

So, write following line of code at top of your class.

```
var arrCarMarkers = [GMSMarker]()
```

Then after, store every marker in this array which are you placing on map.

So, update your code as follow:

```
func displayIt() {
    if self.carNumber == "1" {
        carMarker.map = self.mapView
        arrCarMarkers.append(carMarker) // Here is store marker in array
    } else {
        carMarker.map = nil
    }
}
```

Now, you have all marker which are placed on map. So when you want to remove these markers just update your code as follow:

```
@IBAction func showCar(_ sender: Any) {
    if motorisedVehicleButtonActive {
        motorisedVehicleButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "carO"), for: .normal)
        carNumber = "1"
        showCarIcon()
    } else {
        motorisedVehicleButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "car"), for: .normal)
        carNumber = "0"
        self.arrCarMarkers.forEach { $0.map = nil }
    }
    print(carNumber)
    motorisedVehicleButtonActive = !motorisedVehicleButtonActive
}
```

**Above code will remove all markers from map.**

I hope this will works for you.